# AppStore Connect Review - Rejected

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

So In my app the user is able to open a speific level by rating the app. The message prompt in my app goes like this:

```
Do you want to rate the app 5 stars to open level X for free?
```

Now, that made the app **rejected**, with this message:

> Guideline 3.2.2 - Business - Other Business Model Issues -
> Unacceptable
>
> We noticed that your app prompts users to rate the app in exchange for
> in-app currency, points, or other incentives. Incentivizing ratings
> and downloads has a direct influence on the App Store user reviews or
> chart ranking.

Does that mean that I can't ask the user to rate my app at all - to unlock the level, or can I? Can I change the message to something like this:

```
Do you want to rate the app to open level X?
```

Would this be approved?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because App Store rejection and policy is off topic. From the `appstore-approval` [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appstore-approval): "App store approval is off-topic for Stack Overflow." It's not our place to guess what Apple will do. This is between you and Apple. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Clause 3.2.2 (vi) in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#unacceptable) states:

> Apps should allow a user to get what they’ve paid for without performing additional tasks, such as posting on social media, uploading contacts, checking in to the app a certain number of times, etc. **Apps should not require users to rate the app**, review the app, watch videos, download other apps, tap on advertisements, enable tracking, or take other similar actions **in order to access functionality, content**, use the app, or receive monetary or other compensation, including but not limited to gift cards and codes.

So, no, you cannot ask the user to review your app in order to access an additional level.